# Capturar valores de uma tabela e inseri-los em outra

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tsql

Possuo uma tabela temporária que a preencho com resultado de uma determinada consulta. Agora preciso percorrer os dados dessa tabela temporária, linha a linha, e pegar determinados campos e inseri-los em outra tabela, e nessa outra tabela, gerar um código de cupom, com um sequencial específico, para assim concluir o processo.

Como posso o fazer esse loop de capturar linha a linha da tabela temporária?

```
    CREATE TABLE #PontosVPAcimaCem (
        qtd_cupons INT
        ,apuracao_ptsvp NUMERIC(14, 2)
        ,apuracao_mesfch INT
        ,apuracao_anofch INT
        ,apuracao_id_client INT
        ,clients_username NVARCHAR(150)
        )

    INSERT INTO #PontosVPAcimaCem (
        qtd_cupons
        ,apuracao_ptsvp
        ,apuracao_mesfch
        ,apuracao_anofch
        ,apuracao_id_client
        ,clients_username
        )
    SELECT CAST(a.ptsvp / 100 AS INT)
        ,a.ptsvp
        ,a.mesfch
        ,a.anofch
        ,a.id_client
        ,c.username
    FROM t_clients c WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN gr_apuracao a WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.id = a.id_client
    WHERE a.mesfch = @apuracao_mes
        AND a.anofch = @apuracao_ano
        AND a.ptsvp >= @apuracao_pontosvp

    SELECT qtd_cupons
        ,apuracao_ptsvp
        ,apuracao_mesfch
        ,apuracao_anofch
        ,apuracao_id_client
        ,clients_username
    FROM #PontosVPAcimaCem WITH (NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY qtd_cupons DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando cursor. Nesta thread há a resposta.

[Percorrer linha a linha de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172428/percorrer-linha-a-linha-de-uma-tabela/172441#172441)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `SQL INSERT INTO SELECT`

Que tem por função copiar os dados de uma tabela para outra existente.

Exemplo sem a declaração das colunas a serem inseridas, que pode ser usado em casos onde você está copiando os dados entre duas tabelas com a mesma estrutura

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outro possibilidade é de você declarar as colunas.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```