# Percorrer linha a linha de uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Possuo uma tabela temporária que a preencho com resultado de uma determinada consulta.

Preciso percorrer os dados dessa tabela temporária, linha a linha, e pegar determinados campos e inseri-los em outra tabela, e nessa outra tabela, gerar um código de cupom, com um sequencial específico, para assim concluir o processo.

Não consigo simplesmente usar o INSERT INTO ... SELECT (como uso em meu script em outros pontos)

Como posso o fazer esse loop de capturar linha a linha da tabela temporária?

```
CREATE TABLE #PontosVPAcimaCem (
    qtd_cupons INT
    ,apuracao_ptsvp NUMERIC(14, 2)
    ,apuracao_mesfch INT
    ,apuracao_anofch INT
    ,apuracao_id_client INT
    ,clients_username NVARCHAR(150)
    )

INSERT INTO #PontosVPAcimaCem (
    qtd_cupons
    ,apuracao_ptsvp
    ,apuracao_mesfch
    ,apuracao_anofch
    ,apuracao_id_client
    ,clients_username
    )
SELECT CAST(a.ptsvp / 100 AS INT)
    ,a.ptsvp
    ,a.mesfch
    ,a.anofch
    ,a.id_client
    ,c.username
FROM t_clients c WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN gr_apuracao a WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.id = a.id_client
WHERE a.mesfch = @apuracao_mes
    AND a.anofch = @apuracao_ano
    AND a.ptsvp >= @apuracao_pontosvp

SELECT qtd_cupons
    ,apuracao_ptsvp
    ,apuracao_mesfch
    ,apuracao_anofch
    ,apuracao_id_client
    ,clients_username
FROM #PontosVPAcimaCem WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY qtd_cupons DESC
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar `Cursor`? Com ele você pode consultar e manipular as informações no `select` da tabela temporária e fazer os tratamentos linha a linha.

Comment: @Willian não tentei usar. Preciso aprender sobre para poder utilizar, pois sou iniciante em SQL. Teria algum artigo para compartilhar, por favor?

Comment: Você pode olhar nesses aqui: http://www.devmedia.com.br/cursores-no-sqlserver/5590. Vou montar uma resposta para tentar simplificar porque é um conceito mais avançado e eu mesmo tive uma certa dificuldade para entender

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Capturar valores de uma tabela e inseri-los em outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172390/capturar-valores-de-uma-tabela-e-inseri-los-em-outra)

Comment: @JoséDiz sim, de fato. Não consegui excluir o tópico que mencionou, infelizmente o título não condizia com o que eu precisava, tentei editá-lo, porém não foi possível.

Comment: @FelipeNegro Conseguiu resolver o problema usando o Cursor?

Comment: @FelipeNegro: Como é gerado o código do cupom? Quais são as regras para inserir os dados na "outra tabela"? Qual o nome e estrutura da "outra tabela"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o seu problema pode ser resolvido utilizando cursor. Nele você pode fazer tratamentos linha-a-linha e implementar os tratamentos que deseja.

```
DECLARE @vQtd_cupons varchar(50)
       ,@vApuracao_ptsvp varchar(50)
       ,@vApuracao_mesfch varchar(50)
       ,@vApuracao_anofch varchar(50)
       ,@vApuracao_id_client varchar(50)
       ,@vClients_username varchar(50)

-- Declaração do cursor. Nesse ponto você especifica a qual consulta o cursor irá manipular
DECLARE Crs_teste CURSOR FOR
SELECT qtd_cupons
      ,apuracao_ptsvp
      ,apuracao_mesfch
      ,apuracao_anofch
      ,apuracao_id_client
      ,clients_username
from #tmp_teste

-- Abertura do cursor. Aqui a consulta é feita e o Cursor mantem as informações
OPEN Crs_teste 

-- Recupera a linha do cursor 
FETCH Crs_teste 
-- Define o valor das variáveis com os valores da linha que ele está percorrendo. 
-- É importante que as variáveis estejam na mesma ordem que as colunas na consulta
INTO @vQtd_cupons
    ,@vApuracao_ptsvp
    ,@vApuracao_mesfch
    ,@vApuracao_anofch
    ,@vApuracao_id_client
    ,@vClients_username

-- Loop. O Fetch_Status retorna os valores 0 [Ok], -1[Falha] e -2 [Registro perdido]
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  /* Tratamentos para geração do Código de barras
  ** Insert into em outra tabela
  **
  */

  -- Passa para o proximo registro, caso seja o ultimo registro da consulta, o @@Fetch_status passa a ser -1
  FETCH Crs_teste 
  -- Insere os valores das linhas nas variáveis
  INTO @vQtd_cupons
      ,@vApuracao_ptsvp
      ,@vApuracao_mesfch
      ,@vApuracao_anofch
      ,@vApuracao_id_client
      ,@vClients_username
END
-- Fecha o cursor
CLOSE Crs_teste
-- Remove a referência do cursor. 
DEALLOCATE Crs_teste
```

Você pode utilizar alguns artigos como base de estudos como o :

[MSDN.Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169.aspx)

[DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/cursores-no-sqlserver/5590)

[CodigoMaster](http://www.codigomaster.com.br/banco-de-dados/sqlserver-como-utilizar-cursor-em-uma-consulta)

Existem outros tutoriais e artigos por ai, mas espero que a explicação no código esteja entendivel.